# How to close html tags in cshtml in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Is there a way to close HTML tags if it is outside a foreach statement in the cshtml file? Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. Basically I open the tag inside the loop and want to close the tag outside the loop but VS studio throws an error saying the "The foreach block is missing a closing tag"

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h5>
         @item.Category.CategoryName
}
    </h5> // this doesn't work :(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is there for a reason.  Consider the HTML that your code might create.  Let's say your collection has 5 elements:

```
<h5>Category One
<h5>Category Two
<h5>Category Three
<h5>Category Four
<h5>Category Five
</h5>
```

Clearly this is invalid HTML, and the error is there to prevent that.

Either close the tag within the loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h5>@item.Category.CategoryName</h5>
}
```

Or open it before the loop:

```
<h5>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.Category.CategoryName
}
</h5>
```